# Perl JSON package unable to load JSON file -> expecting unexpected characters

Tags: json, perl

I'm attempting to load fitness data from FitBit that looks like this:

```
[{
  "dateTime" : "03/16/19 05:02:00",
  "value" : "0"
},{
  "dateTime" : "03/16/19 05:05:00",
  "value" : "0"
},{

... about 64,800 lines here

},{
  "dateTime" : "04/15/19 04:47:00",
  "value" : "0"
},{
  "dateTime" : "04/15/19 04:58:00",
  "value" : "0"
}]
```

I attempt to read this in to Perl using the JSON package like this:

```
sub json_file_to_hash {
   my $file = shift;
   open my $in, '<', $file;
   my $json = <$in>;
   close $in;
   $json = "$json\n";
   my $ref = decode_json $json;
   return %{ $ref }
}
```

When I run this on Perl, I get this:

`'"' expected, at character offset 4 (before "(end of string)") at fitbit.pl line 15.`

This error doesn't make any sense.  It makes it seem as if the strings aren't enclosed by strings.

How can I load this file into a hash using the JSON package?

Comment: Tip: Get used to working with reference. You shouldn't be returning the individual keys and values of the hash to build a new hash from them in the caller instead of a reference to the hash. Bad: `return %{ $ref }`. Good: `return $ref`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are only reading the 1st line of your input file, not all lines of the file:

```
my $json = <$in>;
```

You could slurp all lines by changing the default [INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR $/](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

```
sub json_file_to_hash {
    my $file = shift;
    local $/;
    open my $in, '<', $file;
    my $json = <$in>;
    close $in;
    my $ref = decode_json $json;
    return %{ $ref }
}
```